# Is it faster to update the whole table, or to use WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Which is the faster way to execute a query that updates a lot of rows?

The first query example will update the points column to 0, for every rows that the last_visit is made from 7 days and before.

After, in both cases, there is an additional query that writes in all rows that the last_visit was made on the last 7 days.

The table now has about 140.000 rows. The first query updates 110.000 rows and the second 140.000

```
UPDATE the_table SET points = 0 where DATE(last_visit) <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND type is NULL
```

or

```
UPDATE the_table SET points = 0 where type is NULL
```

Comment: If you use the Where clause how many rows are normally updated?

Comment: Both options you provide use a where clause.

Comment: Both queries affect different data... one for the last 7 days, the other for everything before those 7 days.

Comment: @KenWhite consider turning your comment into an answer!

Comment: @KenWhite i will not reply regarding your answer. but man, you won the internet today. As an experienced debater, you have a great argument there.

Comment: @ChrisM the first query updates 110.000 rows and the second 140.000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two `UPDATES` do far different things and both use `WHERE` clauses, so any speed comparison is useless. The first checks both for a 7 day period AND the type being NULL, while the second only checks the second condition. They can potentially affect vastly different amounts of data (which your edit shows).

Asking which is faster is akin to saying "I have a dump truck and a Ferrari. Which is faster?" - the answer depends on whether you're going to move 10 tons of sand or go zero to 60 to merge into highway traffic. Your `UPDATE` performance doesn't make any more sense - it depends on which rows you actually want to `UPDATE`. Use the one that does what you really want to do and stop worrying about which is faster.

Before doing an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` that will affect a lot of rows, it's always a good idea to run a `SELECT` using the same `WHERE` clause to see if the data that is going to be updated is what you expect. You'll appreciate it the first time you realize that you were about to execute an `UPDATE` with the wrong conditions that would have caused major problems or a `DELETE` that would have lost valuable data.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and of course the logic behind it. Practically, the first query updates 110.000 rows and the second 140.000.

Comment: So which do you really want to do? 30,000 rows difference is a big deal.

Comment: I want to go with the faster, even if is the one that updates 30.000 rows more

Comment: That's the wrong choice. The correct one is **the one that updates the data you actually want updated**. If you're choosing the wrong one just because it's faster, you're being foolish.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will change my logic.